# Applications of Generalized Geometry to Theoretical Physics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, physics

I'm looking for some topics on Generalized Geometry applied to Physics for a master thesis. I took an introductory course last year, and I have a degree in both Mathematics and Physics. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Edit: For a short explanation of what I refer to with Generalized Geometry check the comment by Joseph.

Comment: What's "Generalized geometry"?

Comment: Joseph has already given a quite short definition of what I was referring to with "Generalized Geometry". As a side note, if I'm not mistaken, the term "Generalized" can also hint the fact that it can also generalize both symplectic and complex geometry.

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, only an attempt to clarify.
I'm guessing this is what is meant by "generalized geometry":

> "Generalized geometry is based on two premises – the first is to replace the tangent
>   bundle $T$ of a manifold $M$ by $T \oplus T^*$, and the second to replace the Lie bracket on
>   sections of $T$ by the Courant bracket. The idea then is to use one’s experience of
>   differential geometry and by analogy to define and develop the generalized version.
>   Depending on the object, this may or may not be a fertile process, but the intriguing
>   fact is that, by drawing on the intuition of a mathematician, one may often obtain
>   this way a topic which is also of interest to the theoretical physicist."

The quote is from:

> Hitchin, Nigel. "Lectures on generalized geometry." 
>   [arXiv:1008.0973](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0973) (2010).
>   52 pages; based on *JCAS Lecture Series* in Hong Kong.